# Step function unit test case failing

Tags: unit-testing, junit, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

Unit test case is passing when it is awsStepFunctionsAsyncClient.startExecutionAsync but failing for awsStepFunctionsAsyncClient.startExecution

```
 @Test
public void testStateMachineExecutionSuccess(){
    IngestionWorkflowMetadata executionInputs = prepareStateMachineInputs();
    try{
        when(awsStepFunctionsAsyncClient.startExecution(any(StartExecutionRequest.class))).thenReturn(startExecutionResult);
        stepFunctionUtility.startExecution(executionInputs);
        ArgumentCaptor<StartExecutionRequest> requestCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(StartExecutionRequest.class);
        verify(awsStepFunctionsAsyncClient, times(1)).startExecution(requestCaptor.capture());
        Assert.assertEquals(EXPECTED_STEP_FUNCTION_ARN, requestCaptor.getValue().getStateMachineArn());
        Assert.assertEquals(EXECUTION_ID, requestCaptor.getValue().getName());
        Assert.assertEquals(INPUT_STRING, requestCaptor.getValue().getInput());
    } catch (Exception e){ failTheTest(); }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I think the test case is failing at line

`verify(awsStepFunctionsAsyncClient, times(1)).startExecution(requestCaptor.capture());`

because `awsStepFunctionsAsyncClient.startExecution` is not async. Execution times `times(0)` for **sync** call and execution times `times(1)` for **async** call.